# Auto-generate title field from other columns of Drupal 7 Content Type

Tags: drupal-7

I'm struggling to adjust title field of my "car" content type in Drupal 7. How can I automatically generate title field text by combining for example Manufacturer, car Model, Year columns? Also if you could comment on good use of title field and tactics to avoid/remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Auto Node Title module](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle/).

> "auto_nodetitle" is a small and efficient module that allows hiding of
>   the content title field in the form. To prevent empty content title
>   fields one can configure it to generate the title by a given pattern.
>
> When the token module is installed it's possible to use various node
>   data for the auto generated title - e.g. use the text of a CCK field
>   (since 5.x).

Answer (score 2):

[Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) is a generic approach. Works with any entity type. Uses [Token](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/token) module.

> "Automatic Entity Label" is a small and efficient module that allows
>   hiding of entity label fields. To prevent empty labels it can be
>   configured to generate the label automatically by a given pattern.
>
> This can be used on any entity type, including e.g. for node titles,
>   comment subjects, taxonomy term names and profile2 labels.